# Toilet gurgling/ bubbling and backing up on septic

Tags: toilet, septic, overflow

OK...had my cleanouts inspected and cleared and septic pumped....all fine. So, it has to be from the septic to the drain fields. Have a probe and know where my line is from the septic the fields and plan on checking the line myself. If that line is cleared then it has to be the fields...right? I dont have any soft spots anywhere around the line or the fields. If I dig out that line, what do I expect? Ahuge clog? Is this line under pressure when I take it off? What does the connection look like at the line/field junction? How will I know I have to replace my drain fields?

TY
RMerritt

Answer (score 1):

How long ago did you have the septic tank pumped out before the toilet started having problems? If the toilet problems persisted after the septic was pumped, then the problem is in the drains to the tank. If the problem returned after the tank refilled there may be a problem with the discharge elbow or fitting and the solids are blocking the outlet. If the problem is from the tank discharge to the field, you may need a contractor to correct the problem.